# react-data-grid headerRenderer Sorting

Tags: sorting, react-data-grid

How is sorting and filtering implemented when using a custom header cell in the react-data-grid?

```
{
  key: "myColumn1",
  name: "My Column Name",
  headerRenderer: this.renderHeader,
  sortable: true,
  filterable: true
},
{
  key: "myColumn2",
  name: "My Other Column Name",
  sortable: true,
  filterable: true
}  
  ...

renderHeader(props){
  return  (<extra-stuff>
    {props.column.name}
  </extra-stuff>)
}
```

I have myColumn2 sorting fine but nothing happens with the custom header: myColumn1.  What do I need to do in renderHeader(){} to get sorting (and filtering, but mainly sorting) working?

Comment: btw, a function as value to headerRender works just fine for display a custom header. the sorting is the only thing that doesn't work.  i tried a component but i thought in react you always want functional where possible for efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to call a function in headerRenderer, put a component instead:

```
{
  key: "myColumn1",
  name: "My Column Name",
  headerRenderer: <renderHeader value={this.renderHeader()} />,
  sortable: true,
  filterable: true
},
```

Comment: i tried a component instead of a function and that didn't fix my non-sorting. the headerRenderer is typed to take a func so it should work with a function as well. i must need to do something extra i'm not doing.

Comment: So I did a little more research and you would need a <SortableHeaderCell> component but it is not exported in react-data-grid at this time.  I've tried changing the className to react-grid-HeaderCell-sortable but that doesn't work either. Lastly, I tried onClick={this.  handleGridSort('task','ASC')} but that throws an error. I'm going to keep trying but we may need to fork react-data-grid and export SortableHeaderCell or put it as a request/bug with the author. Your thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a solution was [checked-in](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/pull/572/commits/aadc8459d01ce10813e4bb68ba599c011e9f7eb0) for this almost a year ago.  I do work on an intranet and don't have direct internet access for development so maybe i have an older version.  Since I can't get the version in my environment I'll wait for someone to verify that the latest version works as expected before I accept my own answer (or I'll try to get the latest version with the change in there.)

One other thing I will have to do with the way the solution was implemented is stop propagation of the click event because in my custom header i have a ReactIcon that is clickable to change from status wording to a menu.  So, if they click right on the icon in the header do the name/menu change and if they click anywhere else in the header then do the sort.  I'll have to look up how to do that in React.

### **Update**

I took the changes from the check-in in the link above and added them to my react-data-grid.js and it works great. I.e. I had to add the changes to the pure javascript version of the code that npm pulled into our node_modules.

I also did have to use e.stopPropagation() call in my headerRenderer like i thought i'd have to so that clicking the icon i have in the headerRenderer would not sort when click (but just do a different operation) but it was easy to add.

I do have one question about the change i made to my js which here is a piece of the change...

```
return React.createElement(
  'div',
  {className: className,
   onClick: this.onClick,
   style: {cursor: 'pointer'} },
  React.createElement(
   'span',
   { className: 'pull-right' },
   this.getSortByText()
  ),
  //change was here from just: this.props.column.name
  this.props.column.headerRenderer? this.props.column.headerRenderer(this.props) : this.props.column.name
 );
```

How would i have done this in JavaScript so that it would work whether my headerRenderer was `()=>{ return <span>...</span> }` or `<MyComponent />` ???

Since i always use functions for my headerRenderer i just did the change so that it worked the one way but would like to know how to make the change so it works both ways.  Something like this? ...

```
this.props.column.headerRenderer?
  (isFunction(this.props.column.headerRenderer)? this.props.column.headerRenderer(this.props) : React.createElement(this.props.column.headerRenderer, {...this.props}) )
  : 
  this.props.column.name
```

????